# Include JOGL library in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jogl

I have include the libraries in eclipse, but he can't find the function. Someone can help me please.

I follow this tutorial https://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Setting_up_a_JogAmp_project_in_your_favorite_IDE

and I got this error http://prntscr.com/7819hh

Comment: Please show which source code you try to use. I have used Eclipse with JOGL since 2006 flawlessly. Numerous tutorials not on our wiki are obsolete and some packages have been moved in JOGL 2.3.1.

Answer (score 1):

I already solve the problem. I has importing javax.media.(...) but now I have to import com.jogamp.(...)

Thanks for your help